# SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode always return null (C#)

Tags: c#, xml

I've been having some problems using SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode, because they always seem to return null.
Here's the code I've been using:

```
DialogResult openFDexec = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
if (openFDexec == DialogResult.OK)
{
    filePath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    var fileStream = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
    {

    }
}

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

doc.Load(filePath);

XmlNodeList transaction = doc.SelectNodes("bookstore/book/title");

Console.WriteLine(transaction.Count);
```

The XML example I used is taken from the Microsft Website:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>  
<bookstore xmlns="urn:newbooks-schema">  
  <book genre="novel" style="hardcover">  
    <title>The Handmaid's Tale</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Margaret</first-name>  
      <last-name>Atwood</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>19.95</price>  
  </book>  
  <book genre="novel" style="other">  
    <title>The Poisonwood Bible</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Barbara</first-name>  
      <last-name>Kingsolver</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>11.99</price>  
  </book>  
  <book genre="novel" style="paperback">  
    <title>The Bean Trees</title>  
    <author>  
      <first-name>Barbara</first-name>  
      <last-name>Kingsolver</last-name>  
    </author>  
    <price>5.99</price>  
  </book>  
</bookstore>
```

Comment: The xml is in a namespace, so you'll need to take that into account Take a look at the "Find Node" section at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

maybe you missed the / before "bookstore" in `XmlNodeList transaction = doc.SelectNodes("bookstore/book/title");`

Try with this: `XmlNodeList transaction = doc.SelectNodes("/bookstore/book/title");`

However, here there is an example for selectNodes function:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.LoadXml(myXmlString);

XmlNodeList xnList = xml.SelectNodes("/Names/Name");
foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
{
  string firstName = xn["FirstName"].InnerText;
  string lastName = xn["LastName"].InnerText;
  Console.WriteLine("Name: {0} {1}", firstName, lastName);
}
```